# sscanf multivalue n length values?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, scanf

I have a file which is similar to /etc/passwd (semi-colon separated values), and need to extract all three values per line into variables then compare them to what have been given into the program. Here is my code:

```
  typedef struct _UserModel UserModel;
  struct _UserModel {
      char username[50];
      char email[55];
      char pincode[30];
  };

  void get_user(char *username) {
   ifstream io("test.txt");
   string line;
   while (io.good() && !io.eof()) {
       getline(io, line);
       if (line.length() > 0 && line.substr(0,line.find(":")).compare(username)==0) {
         cout << "found user!\n";
         UserModel tmp;
         sscanf(line.c_str() "%s:%s:%s", tmp.username, tmp.pincode, tmp.email);
         assert(0==strcmp(tmp.username, username));
       }
   }
}
```

I can't strcmp the values as the trailing '\0' mean the strings are different, so the assertion fails. I only really want to hold the memory for the values anyway and not use up memory that I don't need for these values. What do I need to change to get this to work..?

Comment: In C++ you don't need that `typedef struct _UserModel UserModel`. You can simply use `struct UserModel`. And I think you should prefer std::string over `char*`

Comment: how would you declare username/email/pincode as string and still use them in sscanf?

Comment: Because one string constructor signature is `string ( const char * s );`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sscanf is so C'ish.

```
struct UserModel {
  string username;
  string email;
  string pincode;
};

void get_user(char *username) {
  ifstream io("test.txt");
  string line;
  while (getline(io, line)) {
    UserModel tmp;
    istringstream str(line);
    if (getline(str, tmp.username, ':') && getline(str, tmp.pincode, ':') && getline(str, tmp.email)) {
      if (username == tmp.username)
        cout << "found user!\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I like sscanf :) Great example though, doesn't solve the existing issue though, as the struct defines a staticly size char array which isn't comparing to the give username. (IOW the assertion still fails)

Comment: error: variable ‘std::istringstream str’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: `error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘size_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’` when doing `getline(str, tmp.username, ":");`

Comment: That's what I get for not compiling. Changing ":" to ':' in answer now

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++, I would try to use `std::string`, iostreams and all those things that come with C++, but then again...

I understand that your problem is that one of the C strings is null terminated, while the other is not, and then the `strcmp` is stepping to the `'\0'` on one string, but the other has another value... if that is the only thing you want to change, use `strncpy` with the length of the string that is known.

Comment: all good points! strncpy is probably what I should be using when comparing to C strings, thanks for reminding me!! :)

Comment: @tommed: I don't usually do C, but you there are also some format modifiers that can be passed to `scanf` to retrieve the number of characters read, and you might be able to use that to add a '\0' at the appropriate position in the read char buffers, which will make the strings a little more *safe* if used with other functions like `strlen` and the like.

Comment: Yeh, I think it's something like %n - it's all coming back to me now?! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example that does what I think you asked about.

Things you didn't ask for but it does anyway:

- It uses exceptions to report data file format errors so that `GetModelForUser()` can simply return an object (instead of a boolean or something like that).
- It uses a template function for splitting the line into fields.   This really the heart of the original question and so it's a bit unfortunate that this is arguably over-complex.   But the idea here of making it a template function is that this separates the concerns of splitting a string into fields from choosing a data structure to represent the result.

`/* Parses a file of user data.
 * The data file is of this format:
 * username:email-address:pincode
 *
 * The pincode field is actually one-way-encrypted with a secret salt
 * in order to avoid catastrophic loss of customer data when the file
 * or a backup tape is lost/leaked/compromised.  However, this code
 * simply treats it as an opaque value.
 *
 * Internationalisation: this code assumes that the data file is
 * encoded in the execution character set, whatever that is.  This
 * means that updates to the file must first transcode the
 * username/mail-address/pincode data into the execution character
 * set.
 */`

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>

const char* MODEL_DATA_FILE_NAME = "test.txt";

// This stuff should really go in a header file.
class UserUnknown : public std::exception { };

class ModelDataIsMissing : public std::exception { };
class InvalidModelData : public std::exception { }; // base: don't throw this directly.
class ModelDataBlankLine : public InvalidModelData { };
class ModelDataEmptyUsername : public InvalidModelData { };
class ModelDataWrongNumberOfFields : public InvalidModelData { };

class UserModel {
    std::string username_;
    std::string email_address_;
    std::string pincode_;

public:
    UserModel(std::string username, std::string email_address, std::string pincode)
    : username_(username), email_address_(email_address), pincode_(pincode) {
    }
    UserModel(const UserModel& other)
    : username_(other.username_),
      email_address_(other.email_address_),
      pincode_(other.pincode_) {
    }

```
std::string GetUsername() const { return username_; }
std::string GetEmailAddress() const { return email_address_; }
std::string GetPincode() const { return pincode_; }
```

};

UserModel GetUserModelForUser(const std::string& username) 
    throw (InvalidModelData, UserUnknown, ModelDataIsMissing);

// This stuff is the implementation. 
namespace {  // use empty namespace for modularity.
    template  void SplitStringOnSeparator(
    std::string input, char separator, ForwardIterator output) 
    {
    std::string::const_iterator field_start, pos;
    bool in_field = false;
    for (pos = input.begin(); pos != input.end(); ++pos) {
                if (!in_field) {
        field_start = pos;
        in_field = true;
        }
        if (*pos == separator) {
        *output++ = std::string(field_start, pos);
        in_field = false;
        }
    }
    if (field_start != input.begin()) {
        *output++ = std::string(field_start, pos);
    }
    }
}

// Returns a UserModel instance for the specified user.
//
// Don't call this more than once per program invocation, because
// you'll end up with quadratic performance.  Instead modify this code
// to return a map from username to model data.
UserModel GetUserModelForUser(const std::string& username) 
    throw (InvalidModelData, UserUnknown, ModelDataIsMissing)
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream in(MODEL_DATA_FILE_NAME);
    if (!in) {
    throw ModelDataIsMissing();
    }

```
while (std::getline(in, line)) {
std::vector<std::string> fields;
SplitStringOnSeparator(line, ':', std::back_inserter(fields));
if (fields.size() == 0) {
    throw ModelDataBlankLine();
} else if (fields.size() != 3) {
    throw ModelDataWrongNumberOfFields();
} else if (fields[0].empty()) {
    throw ModelDataEmptyUsername();
} else if (fields[0] == username) {
    return UserModel(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]);
}
// We don't diagnose duplicate usernames in the file.
}
throw UserUnknown();
```

}

namespace {
    bool Example (const char *arg) 
    {
    const std::string username(arg);
    try
    {
        UserModel mod(GetUserModelForUser(username));
        std::cout << "Model data for " << username << ": "
              << "username=" << mod.GetUsername()
                  << ", email address=" << mod.GetEmailAddress()
              << ", encrypted pin code=" << mod.GetPincode()
              << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    catch (UserUnknown) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown user " << username << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i, returnval=0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
    try 
    {
        if (!Example(argv[i])) {
        returnval = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidModelData) {
        std::cerr << "Data file " << MODEL_DATA_FILE_NAME << " is invalid." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (ModelDataIsMissing) {
        std::cerr << "Data file " << MODEL_DATA_FILE_NAME << " is missing." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    }
    return returnval;
}

/* Local Variables: */
/* c-file-style: "stroustrup" */
/* End: */

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with `strcmp`, but you have one in your sscanf format.  `%s` will read upto the first non white character, so it will read the `:`.  You probably want `"%50[^:]:%55[^:]:%30s"` as format string.  I've added field size in order to prevent buffer overflow, but I could be off by one in the limit.